# Using output of one query, as input to another

Tags: sql

Got a puzzler here.

Let's say I have a table called **MASTER_TABLE** which has 2 columns, **TABLE_NAME** and **FIELD_NAME**. This table stores the name of another table and some random column of that table. For example:
**MASTER_TABLE** has the following data:

```
TABLE_NAME    FIELD_NAME

Employee      Emp_name

Employee      Emp_ID

Department    Dept_name

Department    Dept_loc

Headquarters  HQ_name
```

I want to create a query that will loop through the records in this master table, which will go on to create another count query on **TABLE_NAME** and look at **FIELD_NAME** to check if that column is `NULL` or not.

For example, there is another table called *EMPLOYEE* with multiple columns including **Emp_name**, **Emp_ID** and so on. I wish to do the following:

`Select count(*) from Employee where Emp_name is null;`

And then another query to count the number of **Emp_IDs** which are `NULL`.

Thing is, I don't want to write a specific query for every record in **MASTER_TABLE**. Any thoughts?

Comment: What database you are using? What you need calls for dynamic SQL generation, and that is done differently in different RDBMS's.

Comment: First, you probably don't need your master table.  Most RDBMSs have system tables with the same data as you have in your question.  Next, there is no need to check the primary key fields.  They are not allowed to be null.  Finally, this would probably be easier to achieve with application code such as ColdFusion or .net than with straight sql.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'm using Oracle

Comment: Then you don't need a master table.

Comment: I need to keep the master table as it stores which column I need to null check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code for dynamic query in MSSQL

```
declare @tablename as nvarchar(50), @fieldname as nvarchar(50), @qry as nvarchar(500);
set @tablename = 'Employee';
set @fieldname = 'Emp_ID';
set @qry = 'select count(*) as ''Number of Rows'' from ' + @tablename + ' where ' + @fieldname + ' is null';

exec sp_executesql @qry
```

All you need is a `while` loop fetching `cursor` for each record in **MASTER_TABLE** and `set` *@tablename* to TABLE_NAME and *@fieldname* to **FIELD_NAME**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I see how you're doing it, but I'm using Oracle. Can it be done similarly using a procedure?

Comment: @user3144072 you'r welcome, and welcome to stackoverflow. You can vote for solutoins you found helpful and accept answers that solved your problem. And your answer: it can be done, but i don't know how. I googled *Oracle Dynamic SQL* and there appears to be an instruction `Execute Immediate <sql_qry_text>`. Refer to : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm